# Can't get proper coordinates for selected objects on canvas

Tags: fabricjs

For example let's create two rectangles.
Then we select these two rectangles and want to see their coordinates:

```
var greyBox = new fabric.Rect({
    left:100,
    top:100,
    fill: 'grey',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

var redBox = new fabric.Rect({
    left:300,
    top:300,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

function createCanvas(id){
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);
    canvas.add(greyBox);
    canvas.add(redBox);

    canvas.on('selection:created', function(e) {
        const activeSelection = e.target;

        console.log(activeSelection._objects[0].left);
        console.log(activeSelection._objects[1].left);
    });

    return canvas;
}
```

We know exactly that their lefts are 100 and 300.
But instead we see this: -150 and 49:
[image: the coords are -150 and 49]

How do we get the proper coords?

Comment: Position of an object within a selection is given relative to the selection, as measured from the center in this case.  Since the width of the selection is 301 (1 extra pixel for the border), the position of the grey box is `-150.5` since it's on the very left edge.  If you account for the position and width of the selection, you'll get the right value, i.e. `-150.5 + 100 + 150.5 = 100`.

Comment: Thanks, it explains the false coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find positional properties of an object in a group or multi-selection you can use the  `calcTransformMatrix()` method.

```
var matrix = activeSelection._objects[0].calcTransformMatrix();
var options = fabric.util.qrDecompose(matrix);
console.log(options.translateX, options.translateY);
```

The options object will have the transformed values you need. See http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations to better understand the transformMatrix system.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. "Var options" doesn't have such property as left/top. Instead it has "angle", "scaleX", "skewX".

Comment: I updated my example. The top/left values within the transform matrix are actually called translateX and translateY. If you're still not having any luck please share a fiddle or code snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Still something's wrong. I know exactly that the coords are top100/left 100. But on the fiddle you see, they are 150.5/150.5. The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ov7z84gx/

Comment: I see the issue. the translateX and translateY values are given assuming an originX and originY of center. Since you're not using a center origin you'll just need to adjust the coords by half the object's width/height